# jQuery replacing img src in three steps

Tags: jquery, gallery, shopify

Bit stuck with this one. I'm building a product image gallery for a Shopify shop that needs to have the following functionality:

1. Thumbnails for each product image
2. Medium-sized image that goes into the main image 'container'
3. Full-sized image that appears as a lightbox when you click the medium-sized image

So, you would click on a thumbnail which would load the medium sized image into the image container and then clicking on that medium sized image would show the full size image as a lightbox overlay.

Here's my mark up:

```
<div id="imgcontainer">
                <a href="assets/product-fullsize.jpg" class="overlay"><img src="assets/product-main.jpg" alt="product-main" width="360" height="231" /></a>
            </div> <!-- End div#imgcontainer -->
            <div id="thumbs">
                <div class="thumbnav">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="assets/medium-1.jpg"><img src="assets/thumb-1.jpg" alt="thumb-1" width="100" height="70" /></a></li>
                        <li><a href="assets/medium-2.jpg"><img src="assets/thumb-2.jpg" alt="thumb-2" width="100" height="70" /></a></li>
                        <li><a href="assets/medium-3.jpg"><img src="assets/thumb-3.jpg" alt="thumb-3" width="100" height="70" /></a></li>
                        <li><a href="assets/medium-1.jpg"><img src="assets/thumb-1.jpg" alt="thumb-1" width="100" height="70" /></a></li>
                        <li><a href="assets/medium-2.jpg"><img src="assets/thumb-2.jpg" alt="thumb-2" width="100" height="70" /></a></li>
                        <li><a href="assets/medium-3.jpg"><img src="assets/thumb-3.jpg" alt="thumb-3" width="100" height="70" /></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div> <!-- End div#thumbnav -->
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="tbpr">&nbsp;</a>
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="tbnx">&nbsp;</a>
            </div> <!-- End div#thumbs -->
        </div> <!-- End div#main -->
```

Can anyone recommend the best way to do this? Shopify uses a language called 'Liquid' that lets me use a 'foreach' statement to output markup for the images, or even just the three types of image urls (thumbnail, medium and fullsize).

Note that there is no simple naming convention for the image filename and location as they are generated on the fly, so I can't just swap out the 'medium' part of the filename for 'fullsize' etc.

Thanks for any pointers,

Osu

Comment: How do you expect anyone to write a JS function for something that has no proper name, only something randomly generated "on the fly", there must be some sort of system for this, otherwise how will it find the correct image for any given product. I'm sure someone will still give you a few general ideas though.

Comment: @adenao, i am assuming that he can have access to the filename but it is not just a predefined prefix/suffix for each size..

Comment: Well, Osu clearly writes that "there is no simple naming convention for filename/location" and that the part of the image that describes the size ie. thumb/medium/fullsize can't just be swapped out. Either the question is amazingly badly formed, or the answers thus far are wrong. Since Osu also writes that it actually is possible to generate the image file names with said descrition in Shopify, I'll assume it is the former, that the question is badly formed, and that the answers are correct.

Comment: adeneo, apologies it wasn't clear enough - all I was trying to say was that the image urls used by Shopify don't appear to have a common pattern to them, so I don't think I can hook on to something like the name to just swap a word like 'medium' for 'fullsize' to change the main image in the container. I'm sure you appreciate it can be difficult to verbalize these things sometimes. @tvanfosson and Gaby, thanks for your answers. At first glance, they both look like they're the right kind of thing, so I'm going to  try them out and get back to you both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you store the full-size urls as a data attribute on the anchors? E.g.,

```
<li><a href="assets/medium-1.jpg" data-fullsize="assets/fullsize-1.jpg">
       <img src="assets/thumb-1.jpg" alt="..." /></a></li>
```

Then you could use something like:

```
$('a[data-fullsize]').click( function() {
     var $this = $(this);
     $('#imgcontainer a:first').attr('href',$this.data('fullsize'))
                               .find('img')
                               .attr('src',$this.attr('href'));
     return false;
});
$('#imgcontainer').on('click','a:first',function() {
     // load href into lightbox
     return false;
});
```

Comment: Absolutely fantastic. This works a dream (there's a missing bracket on `.attr('src',$this.attr('href'));`, but other than that, superb. Thank you!

Comment: just a quick question, if I wanted to create fade in and out transitions when clicking the thumbnails, do you know how I'd do it? I tried chaining on fadeIn and fadeOut before ´.find('img')´ but it wasn't very satisfactory as the images appeared then disappeared and faded in! Thanks

Comment: You should chain the rest in the callback to the fadeOut.  `.find('img').fadeOut( function() { $(this).attr('src', $this.attr('href')).fadeIn(); })`  You probably want to pick a more appropriate name than `$this` to store the anchor being clicked on to avoid confusion in the callback.

Comment: yet again, a great solution. I bow to your knowledge, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I would add the path to the link as a data attribute..

**adding the large image info**

```
<li><a href="assets/medium-1.jpg" data-zoomimage="assets/big-1.jpg"><img src="assets/thumb-1.jpg" alt="thumb-1" width="100" height="70" /></a></li>
```

**handling the clicks** (*jQuery v1.7*)

*first for the thumbs -> medium*

```
$('.thumbnav').on('click','a',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var self = $(this);
    $('#imgcontainer a') // find the link 
        .attr('href',self.data('zoomimage') ) // and update its href to point to the zoom
        .find('img') // fint the image inside
        .attr('src', self.attr('href') ); // and load the medium
});
```

*then for the medium -> zoom*

```
$('#imgcontainer').on('click','a',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var self = $(this);
    // use lightbox system to load the link's href.. self.attr('href')
});
```

Comment: many thanks for your answer too - both of these seem to work, so thanks for taking the time to respond